# Regular expression for editing yaml file

Tags: regex, sed, yaml

I have the following configuration file `config.yml.example`

```yaml
development:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
test:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
production:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

I am trying to modify one of the keys in the production configuration using a bash script.

```sh
for example_file in *.example; do
  if [ `basename ${example_file}` == "config.yml.example" ]; then
    sed -i '.bak' 's/\(.*key3:.*\)/key3: my_new_value/g' $example_file
  fi
  cp "$example_file" "$(basename "$example_file" .example)"
done
```

The problem is `'s/\(.*key3:.*\)/key3: my_new_value/g'` is replacing the value of key3 under `development` and not `production`. 
What would be the right regular expression to use in this case?

Comment: sed is line oriented tool by default, and the command you tried will replace all the three matches in the given sample input.. there are tools like https://github.com/mikefarah/yq that could help you better with yaml files than sed

Comment: Rather than `for f in *; do if [ "$f" = "foo" ]; then x "$f"; fi; y "$f"; done` consider `x "foo"; for f in *; do y "$f"; done`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be better served with tools like https://github.com/mikefarah/yq for yaml input files. In case you cannot install such tools, `awk` would suit better than `sed` for this case.

```
$ awk '/^[^[:space:]]/{f=/^production/} f && /key3/{$0="  key3: my_new_value"} 1' ip.txt
development:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
test:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
production:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: my_new_value
```

- `/^[^[:space:]]/{f=/^production/}` am making a guess here, if a line doesn't start with a whitespace character, then use a flag to know if the heading is `production` or not
- `f && /key3/` if flag is set and line contains `key3`

  - `$0="  key3: my_new_value"` change the line to new value
  - note that `f` will be unset on the next heading, assuming it won't be `production`
- `1` a true condition, idiomatic way to print contents of input record `$0`

For inplace editing, use `-i inplace` if you have `GNU awk`

Answer (score 2):

On mikefarah/yq v4 and above, you could simply do

```
yq e '.production.key3 |= "newvalue"' config.yml.example
```

---

The below suggestions work only on `yq` versions <4. The recent versions have a much improved DSL, like that of `jq`

YAML parsers are much more suited for this. Using [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), all you need to do it provide the path expression for the key you modifying and set the desired value for it.

```
yq w config.yml.example production.key3 my_new_value
```

It even supports a in-place edit of the YAML file like `sed -i`, you just need to add `-i` flag after write flag `w`. There are other options for formatting the value also, e.g. if you want to quote the value as a string type as `"my_new_value"`, you can apply [styles](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/value-parsing#the-style-flag)

```
yq w config.yml.example production.key3 --style=double my_new_value
```

There is also [kislyuk-yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#installation), which is another YAML parser that relies on JSON parser `jq` that modifies content in JSON context and puts it back to YAML with `-y` flag. So you could do below.

```
yq -y 'with_entries(select(.key == "production").value.key3 = "new_value")' config.yml.example
```

Note that `'..'` definition is purely a `jq` filter expression which is applied to the JSON converted from YAML. Without the `-y` flag the result would be a JSON blob by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the `key3` value under `production`, a different approach with `sed` could consist of reading the file in reverse order, then replace the first match, and then read it in reverse order again so your output is brought normally. For example, this:

```
tac $example_file | sed "0,\|value3|{s|value3|mynewvalue|}" | tac
```

Would return this output:

```
development:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
test:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
production:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: mynewvalue
```